# Jenkins not responding when click on Releases link sing Subversion Release Manager plugin

Tags: svn, jenkins

I install the Subversion Release Manager plugin, and configured a project according to this: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Release+Manager

However, when I click the Release link in the left panel, the browse just clocking forever ... There is  no information find in /var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log

How can I toubleshoot this?

Thanks
Jirong